# VK API Не могу получить список друзей моего друга

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я пытаюсь получить информацию о друзьях моего друга. Делаю запрос, в поле `user_ids` ввожу айди моего друга. Но вместо его друзей я вижу своих друзей. Может я что-то не понимаю, объясните пожалуйста.

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_ids=ТУТ_ID&fields=bdate&access_token=ТУТ_ТОКЕН"
data = requests.get(url).json()
print(data)
```

P.s. Я только начал разбираться с API, поэтому ошибка может быть действительно глупая. Но я прочитал документацию и не смог понять, что у меня не так.

Comment: Я разобрался, если кому-то будет полезно, то в запросе надо писать не user_ids, а user_id

Answer (score 0):

Как написал автор вопроса в комментариях, проблема была в опечатке, нужно использовать не `user_ids`, а `user_id`.

```py
url = "https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=ТУТ_ID&fields=bdate&access_token=ТУТ_ТОКЕН"
data = requests.get(url).json()
print(data)
```